# Second optional argument for theorem

Tags: ntheorem

I am using `ntheorem` to include theorems in my thesis. Currently, my theorem headers are printed as follows: **(x.y) Theorem (Title).**

The code I use to achieve this is roughly as follows.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}             
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}         
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}    % Definitionen, Sätze, ...                  

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{nummermitklammern}
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep (##2)\ ##1.\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep (##2)\ ##1 (##3).\theorem@separator]}%
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{nummermitklammern}

\newtheorem{x}{}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}[x]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Title]
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to do now is to be able to provide a second optional argument when inserting a theorem, for example a source. If a source is provided, I would like to have the theorem header printed as: **(x.y) Theorem (Title) [Source].**

Is there some way to do this? Note that I have other theorem-like environments like corollary and example defined (that use the same counter as theorem), which I would like to behave the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pseudo-dirty hack that seems to work (in this case at least, I don't know if it will fail in another situations)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}             
\usepackage{mathtools}         
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{nummermitklammern}
  {\finaslonchasnummermitklammernaux{##1}{##2}}
  {\finaslonchasnummermitklammernaux{##1}{##2}[##3]}
\NewDocumentCommand\finaslonchasnummermitklammernaux{mmou\ignorespaces o}
 {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep
    (#2)\ #1%
    \IfValueT{#3}{ (#3)}%
    \IfValueT{#5}{ [#5]}%
    .\theorem@separator]#4\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{nummermitklammern}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Title][Source]
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Manuel, thanks! But with this solution I can only have this format with theorems that are actually called theorem. Is there a way to apply the same to custom theorem-like environments such as exmaple, corollary, etc.?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, sorry. Gives me a compilation error for the line `\NewDocumentCommand\finaslonchasnummermitklammernaux{mmoo}`.

Comment: Now it works “fine”.

Comment: This is perfect and I want to marry you. Thanks a lot!