# Add argument to theorem environment

Tags: environments, theorems

I want to have a theorem environment with an additional required argument:

```
\begin{mylemma}{text1, text2}
    It holds that True.
\end{mylemma}
\begin{mylemma}{text1, text2}[Name]
    It holds that True.
\end{mylemma}
```

The output should look like this:

**Lemma 1.1** [*text1, text2*]. It holds that True.

**Lemma 1.2** (*Name*) [*text1, text2*]. It holds that True.

I tried using the answers provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/613866/theorem-like-environment-with-optional-title), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289082/second-optional-argument-for-theorem), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83446/how-can-i-make-a-custom-theorem-for-a-definition) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12913/customizing-theorem-name), but got none to work. The closest I got was the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
within=chapter,%
notefont=\normalfont\itshape,%
notebraces={}{},%
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle,name=Lemma]{mydef}
\newenvironment{mylemma}[2]
    {\begin{mydef}[{(}#2{)\ [}#1{]}]}
    {\end{mydef}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{mylemma}{text1, text2}{Name}
It holds that True.
\end{mylemma}
\end{document}
```

This allows me to use `\begin{mylemma}{text1, text2}{Name}\end{mylemma}`, but the argument I want to be optional is now required. Also, it would be nice to be able to write the following instead of defining new environments so verbosely:

```
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{}...{}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{mylemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{mytheorem}[theorem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{mycorollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{myproposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
```

and then being able to use each environment like specified above. I tried to adapt the answer provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289082/second-optional-argument-for-theorem) for that, but apart from then having two *optional* arguments, I got an error possibly related to other packages I use (`Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined. ...rfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}}`). Edit: a MWE for that modification:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage{mathtools, xparse}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
{\isastyleaux{##1}{##2}}
{\isastyleaux{##1}{##2}[##3]}
\NewDocumentCommand\isastyleaux{mmou\ignorespaces o}
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep
    #1\ #2%
    \IfValueT{#3}{\normalfont\itshape (#3)}%
    \IfValueT{#5}{\normalfont\itshape [#5]}%
    .\theorem@separator]#4\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{mylemma}{Lemma}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{mylemma}[text1, text2][Name]
It holds that True.
\end{mylemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example instead of the sniplets. For example it is not listed in any of your sniplets that you are using `ntheorem`

Comment: @daleif I added two MWEs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define an inner theorem and a new environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

% define it to your liking
\newtheorem{mylemmainner}{Lemma}[section]

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylemma}{mo}
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\mylemmainner\textup{[#1]}}{\mylemmainner[#2]\textup{[#1]}} \ignorespaces
 }
 {\endmylemmainner}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{mylemma}{text1, text2}
This is the text of the statement.
\end{mylemma}

\begin{mylemma}{text1, text2}[Name]
This is the text of the statement.
\end{mylemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's how to move the period after the part in square brackets, with `amsthm` (but not `ntheorem` and you shouldn't load both).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{witharg}
  {} % ABOVESPACE
  {} % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape} % BODYFONT
  {0pt} % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {} % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
  {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{ (#3)} \textnormal{[\theoremarg].}}
\newcommand{\theoremarg}{}
  
\theoremstyle{witharg}
\newtheorem{mylemmainner}{Lemma}[section]

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylemma}{mo}
 {%
  \renewcommand{\theoremarg}{#1}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\mylemmainner}{\mylemmainner[#2]}\ignorespaces
 }
 {\endmylemmainner}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{mylemma}{text1, text2}
This is the text of the statement.
\end{mylemma}

\begin{mylemma}{text1, text2}[Name]
This is the text of the statement.
\end{mylemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is almost perfect. In my situation (I now also added MWEs), usually a dot is inserted after the theorem name, and with your code this dot is inserted *before* the brackets: "**Lemma 1.2** (Name). [*text1*, *text2*] Some statement holds." is it possible to insert this dot *after*, i.e. "**Lemma 1.2** (Name) [*text1*, *text2*]. Some statement holds."?

Comment: @JakobW. I added a solution. You shouldn't load both `amsthm` and `ntheorem`. I find the former *much* better.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much for your help!